# Receive notification that user has disabled contacts on iOS

Tags: ios, contacts

I'm using the address book API on iOS to gain access to system contacts. I would like to be notified if the user disables or enables contacts for the application (via the Settings app).

Is there any such notification?

Whilst I am currently using the address book API, I am willing to move to the new (in iOS 9) [contacts framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html) if it provides this feature. Alas, I see no mention of it in the docs.

Can anyone shed light on how one can be notified that the user has modified the contacts access for one's application?

Comment: Have you tried using tools like eg. Mixpanel? This lets you track virtually anything (reports are sent when you open the app though).

Comment: @Rafal: erm, I don't think an analytics product is relevant here. I need programmatic notification so that my app can take appropriate action when the user disables/enables contacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user changes iOS-level privacy permissions such as contacts, location access, photos, microphone etc. for a particular app, that app is killed. So there should be no need to listen for such a notification because the app will be relaunched the next time the user tries to access it.

You can see this happen if you try to change permissions while the app is connected to the debugger - from XCode, it looks like the app crashed.

Comment: By all the gods - you're right! Thanks - this definitely makes things easy.